# Line in 2D space which is sphere in 3D

Tags: geometry

Suppose there is a 2D creature living on the surface of our Earth. How does a line(in fact a straight line in its space, which is essentially a circle for us) look like to it? It obviously cant be infinite because it will know when it's back to the start point. But it won't be a circle as well since the line is "straight". Then it seems that the line just suddenly joints to the origin? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: this might help https://youtu.be/C6kn6nXMWF0

Comment: Hey Shivam, thanks for the link. I am a bit confused here. Everything in 3d space must be 3d to make sense, a plain without height does not make sense to us. This should be the same in 2d and 1d. How can human in 2d space be a line segment and in 1d be a point? At least they should be a filled square(the whole area) and a line. May be it's just because I haven't gone through the book thoroughly.

Comment: But anyways, I can't see direct relation between the Flatland with my question..... The books seems to me is based on a vertically hanging paper in 3d space without curvature

Comment: We live in a 3D world (I think) but we perceive things as 2D pictures. Our eyes see things as 2D pictures only and there is additional information blended in the form of fainter image and smaller image, that's makes our brain to perceive it as 3D image which is actually a 2D image. Also for a being living on the surface of the earth and limited to it, he can't know that the line is curved he'll keep following the line and always think it is straight and he can't know (for sure ) that he has reached the same point (not identical but same) where he started.

Comment: Only when he is able to come out of the 2D world and climb up the third dimension will he know that he is actually circling the sphere.

Comment: But why do u think he can't know the returning to the origin. May be he can ask his friends to stand there haha

Comment: And it is not only about how he perceives this. I  think this is about how lines, not just necessary lines can be defined or manifest itself in a space.

Comment: ohh yes, I don't deny he's got friends. But my point is that on his way he has no way to tell that he is returning to the same point. For example an observer watching him from the third dimension will see him return after he has covered half a journey at the other end of diameter.